# how to check data return from php page to ajax success function

Tags: php, ajax, if-statement

I want to check the success function data using if loop in `ajax` below is the code any one help me.

If the echo part return the success alert will come this the issue for me.

Below is the `javascript` part and `php` part

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#newuserBtn").on("click", function() {
                $("#regform").show();
                $("#loginform").hide();
            });

            $("#submitBtn").on("click", function() {
                var uid = $("#uid").val();
                var pin = $("#inputPassword").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "validation.php",
                    data: {
                        uname: uid,
                        pwd: pin
                    },
                    success: function(value) {
                        if (value == "success") { //problem here 
                            alert();
                        }
                    }
                });

            });

// php code


<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "ipad7*";
$db_name    = "users";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//Gets username value from the URL
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pwd   = $_POST['pwd'];

//Checks if the username is available or not
$query  = "SELECT pin FROM users_details WHERE uid = '$uname'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row["pin"] == $pwd) {
            echo "success";
        } else {
            echo "login fail";
        }
        //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    //echo "login fail";
}
$conn->close();

//echo "fff";
//echo "$result";


?>
```

Comment: try to print your `ajax` response  using `console.log()` and check what you are getting in response

Comment: i tried it displays success in console but when i check using if (value == "success") { //problem here 
                           alert();
                        } alert not comming

Comment: i have tried boolean values insted of string , now working                                                               "if(value==true){}" but i want the solution for string value compartion also

Comment: Try to change the `==` operator to `===` like: `if ($value === 'sexy') {}` Does it work for your case?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there are no extra line ends after the closing`?>` tag in the PHP script? If there are, the string could still look OK when it's shown with console.log, but not be equal.
It's a good idea to remove the closing tag `?>` altogether to avoid errors like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Send your `responce` (*value* in tour code) in `json` encoded format

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#newuserBtn").on("click", function() {
                $("#regform").show();
                $("#loginform").hide();
            });

            $("#submitBtn").on("click", function() {
                var uid = $("#uid").val();
                var pin = $("#inputPassword").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "validation.php",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    data: {
                        uname: uid,
                        pwd: pin
                    },
                    success: function(value) {
                        console.log(value);
                        if (value == "success") { //problem here 
                            alert();
                        }
                    }
                });

            });


</script>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "ipad7*";
$db_name    = "users";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
//Gets username value from the URL
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pwd   = $_POST['pwd'];

//Checks if the username is available or not
$query  = "SELECT pin FROM users_details WHERE uid = '$uname'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if ($row["pin"] == $pwd) {
            // echo "success";
            echo json_encode("success");
            exit();
        } else {
            // echo "login fail";
            echo json_encode("login fail");
            exit();
        }
        //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    //echo "login fail";
}
$conn->close();

//echo "fff";
//echo "$result";


?>
```